# Photocopied spiral bound books in carry-on or checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

Can I carry spiral bound books in checked baggage? I'm traveling to do a training course abroad and I want to take photocopied textbooks that I need for the course. Is it acceptable to carry photocopies of text books? Also is it ok to take spiral bound books?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, yes. Security will not have any concern for such items. Through the X-ray, it will look just like any other spiral book, notebook, activity book, etc.

Now if you are unlucky to be selected for inspection, then depending on the country where you are going, taking something which violates copyright can raise a concern and me even be confiscated or possibly a charge laid, so I would avoid bringing illegal items across international borders but it really depends how serious they take copyright violations. Some places are very tolerant and even will only make an issue if the original author files a complaint but why risk it?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the weight limit, nobody cares how much paper you have in your luggage, checked or carry on. Paper is heavy, though, so watch out for the weight limits.